# Optimize part of javascript code

Tags: javascript, optimization

Could someone help me, how to best optimize below part of javacript code?

I want to make it lightest for browser, but I have no idea - I haven't huge knowledge about javascript.

```
if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
    (function() {
        var parallaxTop = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax-top");
        if ($(".parallax-center").length) {
            var parallaxCenter = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax-center");
            var centerPosition = $(".parallax-center").position().top;
        }

        if ($(".parallax-bottom").length) {
            var parallaxBottom = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax-bottom");
            var bottomPosition = $(".parallax-bottom").position().top;
        }
        var speed = 0.4;
        window.onscroll = function() {

            [].slice.call(parallaxTop).forEach(function(el, i) {
                var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
                    elBackgrounPos = "center " + "-" + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";
                el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
            });
            if ($(".parallax-center").length)
                [].slice.call(parallaxCenter).forEach(function(el, i) {
                    var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
                        elBackgrounPos = "center " + "" + ((windowYOffset - centerPosition) * speed + 1700) + "px";
                    el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
                });
            if ($(".parallax-bottom").length)
                [].slice.call(parallaxBottom).forEach(function(el, i) {
                    var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
                        elBackgrounPos = "center " + "" + ((windowYOffset - bottomPosition) * speed + 1400) + "px";
                    el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
                });
        };
    })();
}
```

Comment: As you've jQuery loaded on page, use it.

Comment: What needs to be optimized exactly? What do you think is the issue that has to be improved?

Comment: Script works properly. I only need to make it fast as it possible.

Comment: If this is working code, you might be better off looking over to codereview.se.